# how to change url without adding another level of path in react router dom 5

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i have an api "**xyz.com/products/**" and i have made an route **xyz.com/products/1**. This will give me an product with the id 1 . And it will render **product page Component** with that product details...But now on that particular product page i have an gallery of related product with their own individual "Link" to open in same product page . but when i click on any one of them ....the url changes like this "xyz.com/product/1/23" but i want only to change path like "**xyz.com/products/1**" --> **"xyz.com/products/23"**

*here is my code snippets*

// ///// route and link both are on App Component/////////////////

// this is the route that i have that matches xyz.com/product/1

```
<Route
  path="/product/:id"
  render={() => (
    <Fragment>
      <ProductContext.Provider value={{ productState, productStateDispatch }}>
        <Product />
        <div className={`overlay ${productState.packageSidebar}`}></div>
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    </Fragment>
  )}
/>;
```

these are links will go on product page

```
<Row title="Our best seller">
{homeState.bestSellerProducts.map((product, index) => (
  <Link
    to={{
      pathname: `/product/${product.id}`,
      search: `type=${product.type}`,
    }}
    className="product-link"
    key={index}
  >
    {" "}
    <Card {...product} />
  </Link>
))}
</Row>
```

//////////////////////////////

// this is in my product component where i have used  one more component called imageGallery inside it. in which we have links////////////

```
{images.map((imgObj, index) => {
    console.log(imgObj);
    return (
      <div className="item" key={index}>
        <Link to={`/${imgObj.id}`} className="product-link">
          <div className="img">
            <img
              height={100}
              width={100}
              src={imgObj.product_image}
              alt="product-img"
            />
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  })}
```

// i know i messing in routing i hope will get solution.... i just want that when i click on any link in this imageGallery component .it should be open inside same product page in which i m already present.. thats it

Comment: I suspect you are building your link paths incorrectly. Can you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. Can we see both your `Router` code for how paths are matched, and the gallery component that is doing the linking?

Comment: hi @DrewReese lets say i have gone to a path xyz.com/product/1 but without going back can i change /1 with any other value. because i have tried and its getting added like xyz.com/product/1/anyOtherValue

Comment: Sure, I see no reason why you couldn't construct a link "/product/anyOtherValue" and do a `push` or `replace` to it. Are you able to include the code examples so we may see what you are working with?

Comment: hi @DrewReese  i have added some code snippets please check them out

Comment: Have you tried ```<Link to={`/product/${imgObj.id}`} className="product-link">```?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks buddy now its working...i was building my link in a wrong way..

Answer (score 0):

Including exact keyword in the Route component might solve your problem, try out!, demo example:

> `<Route exact to='/' component={home} />`